# Is there a way to conform UIScrollView to custom swipes without changing to 2-finger swipes

Tags: ios, swift

I have scroll view with both horizontal and vertical scrolls (PDF View).

So I wanted to add diagonal swipe to that and figured out that after this:

`scrollView?.panGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: swipe)`

swipe works, but whole scroll view started reacting only to 2-finger gestures.
So it would be perfect for me to find a solution to remove this conflict of swipes.

Comment: did you set cancelsTouchesInView to false?

Comment: No, I didn't. Maybe PDFKit did it by default... but I don't think so

Comment: please set it to false and try again

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work :( just nothing changed